# CRON - PHP - file_get_contents to run PHP page and email with CRON

Tags: php, email, cron, file-get-contents

I am trying to setup an end-of-day automated email using a CRON job.

I can get the CRON job to send out a static email, however I am having trouble when trying to use file_get_contents and a php page that then uses mysql queries to get the data from a database and builds the email body.

Need help!
*NOTE- I use a special php mailer for SMTP. This mailer works 100% FINE when sending any static email or sending dynamic emails manually (not CRON).
Just having trouble getting the CRON job to actually access the PHP file and get the data.

Mailer file being run by CRON:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
set_include_path('/Library/WebServer/Documents/pbhsadmin/');
include '_classes/class.phpmailer.php';

    $email = 'EMAIL';
try {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //New instance, with exceptions enabled

    $mail->Subject  = "PBHS Administration - Changes Department Daily Report";  
    $body = file_get_contents('http://localhost/pbhsadmin/_mail/changes_daily.php');
    //$body = 'Testing no get file';
    $body = preg_replace('/\\\\/','', $body); //Strip backslashes

    $mail->From       = "support@pbhs.uservoice.com";
    $mail->FromName   = "PBHS Support";
    $mail->IsSMTP();                           // tell the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Port       = 25;                    // set the SMTP server port
    $mail->Host       = "mail.SERVER.com"; // SMTP server
    $mail->Username   = "EMAIL"     // SMTP server username
    $mail->Password   = "PASSWORD";            // SMTP server password

    $mail->IsSendmail();  // tell the class to use Sendmail

    $mail->AddReplyTo("support@pbhs.uservoice.com","PBHS Support");     

    $mail->AddAddress($email);

    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
    $mail->WordWrap   = 80; // set word wrap

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

    $mail->Send();
    echo 'message sent!';
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}
?>
```

PHP Page using mysql to query database and create email:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Changes Department - Daily Report</title>
</head>
<body>
<?PHP
set_include_path('/Library/WebServer/Documents/pbhsadmin/');
include 'SQL CONNECTION FILE';

$query = "QUERY";
$result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($row['userid']==0)
        $username = 'Unassigned';
    else        
        $username = $row['username'];
    $userid = $row['userid'];
    //GET ALL PROJECTS WORKED ON FOR THIS USER
    $query2 = "QUERY";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2)or die(mysql_error());
echo '
<div class="employee">
<h1>'.$username.'</h1>
<table><tr><th>Site</th><th>Hours Worked</th><th>Total Hours</th><th>Status</th></tr>';
    while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){

        $domain = $row2['domain'];
        $hours = $row2['hours'];
        if($row2['completed']!='0000-00-00 00:00:00')
            $status = 'Completed';
        else
            $status = 'Incomplete';
        $total_hours = $row2['act_hours'];

        echo '<tr><td class="center">'.$domain.'</td><td class="center">'.$hours.'</td><td class="center">'.$total_hours.'</td><td class="center '.$status.'">'.$status.'</td></tr>';
    }
    if(mysql_num_rows($result2)==0)
        echo '<tr><td colspan="4" style="text-align:center;"><i>No Projects Worked On</i></td></tr>';
echo '</table></div>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing " on the line `$mail->Username   = "EMAIL` Not sure if this happened while posting to SO, but if you have display_errors off, this very well may be the source of your problem.

Comment: Yeah that was just a result of my editing out secure information. The problem isn't related to the mailer file at all. If I changed $body= to just a string (i.e. $body = 'testing'), the email gets sent just fine. It has to do with the file_get_contents. I'm thinking something to do with the path or the way a CRON job could actually process the php file on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured it out.
The error was in my  declaration in the html email.
It has to be `<style type="text/css">`

Comment: I guess the php smtp mailer I use is super sensitive with HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your server is not configured to listen on localhost.

Try running this command from the server with the CRON job:

```
wget http://localhost/pbhsadmin/_mail/changes_daily.php > test.html
```

What is the content of test.html after this?  If it doesn't look correct, then you most likely need to put the full domain in the URL instead of localhost.